# PLSQL XMLTable XPath get all tags of furthest depth

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, plsql, xmltable

In PL/SQL is there a way to get all nodes of the furthest depth?

Example 1:

```
<responseObject>
    <response>
        <value1>A</value1>
        <value2>B</value2>
        <error>A11</error>
    <response>
<responseObject>
```

Example 2:

```
<responseObject>
    <response1>A</response1>
    <response2>B</response2>
    <response4>D</response4>
    <random>1</random>
<responseObject>
```

In example 1 I would like to get value1, value2, and error.  In example 2 I would like to get response1, response2, response4, and random.  Currently my XPath is set up as `'/responseObject/*/*'` but that doesn't work for the second case.

Sample Code:

```
DECLARE
  lxml xmltype;
begin
  lxml := 
  xmltype('<responseObject>
              <response>
                  <value1>A</value1>
                  <value2>B</value2>
                  <error>A11</error>
              <response>
           <responseObject>');

  FOR test IN (
    select tag,
           VALUE
    FROM   xmltable('responseObject/*/*'
             passing lxml
             columns
               tag VARCHAR2(128) path 'name()',
               VALUE VARCHAR2(128) path '.'
           ) t
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(test.tag || ' - ' || test.value);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried just getting the value of value1 and value2 without including any path? Can you put some code example of how you are retrieving the values?

Comment: Updated question.  Note that the last node is not necessarily value1/value2.

Comment: Do you have an example of the actual XML you are trying to get this to work with? And use-case? I cant think of a use-case for getting the value of the last attribute.  Usually you want to get the value of a specific attribute.

Comment: I cannot give the actual XML I am using but I am using this to parse SOAP responses.  I am calling different functions and getting different responses but all the responses have the values I need in the last node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22999c/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, xml ) AS
SELECT 1, '<responseObject>
    <response>
        <value1>A</value1>
        <value2>B</value2>
        <error>A11</error>
    </response>
</responseObject>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '<responseObject>
    <response1>A</response1>
    <response2>B</response2>
    <response4>D</response4>
    <random>1</random>
</responseObject>' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id, x.*
FROM   TABLE_NAME t
       CROSS JOIN
       xmltable(
         '/responseObject//*[last()][not(*)]'
         passing XMLType( t.xml )
         COLUMNS
           tag   VARCHAR2(128) path 'name()',
           value VARCHAR2(128) path '.'
       ) x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22999c/8/0)**:

```
| ID |    TAG | VALUE |
|----|--------|-------|
|  1 |  error |   A11 |
|  2 | random |     1 |
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, your answer worked great to get the 'last node' but I worded my question poorly.  I would like to get all the tags of the innermost depth.

Comment: @Mocking Remove `[last()]` - [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63d60/3)

Comment: Works great! Thank you.  I tried modifying your answer to achieve my desired result but I removed [not(*)].  Could you explain what last() and not(*) do?

Comment: `*[*]` will match elements that do have a child - `*[not(*)]` will match elements that do **not** have a child. `*[last()]` restricts the elements found to the last element only.